# Bash If statement null

Tags: bash, if-statement

Looking for the correct syntax that looks at a bash variable and determines if its null, if it is then do ... otherwise continue on.

Perhaps something like `if [ $lastUpdated = null?; then... else...`

Comment: The `bash` documentation uses `null` as a synonym for the empty string.

Answer (score 13):

Just test if the variable is empty:

```
if [ -z "$lastUpdated" ]; then
    # not set
fi
```

Comment: There is a difference between a null-valued variable (assigned the empty string) and an unset variable; this answer does not make detect that distinction.

Comment: @chepner Is there? Please expand on that.

Comment: Prior to any assignment, a variable is unset. `FOO=` (no value give) is equivalent to `FOO=""`, which sets the value of `FOO` to the empty string. The various parameter expansions (`${FOO:-default}` vs `${FOO-default}`, as an example) allow you to make this distinction. A quoted expansion of an unset variable, such as you use, expands to the empty string, so `-z` can not distinguish the two states.

Comment: @chepner Sounds like you should answer the question and win the prize then.

Comment: @trojanfoe Just FYI. While the distinction exists, it's not as common that one *cares* about the distinction :)

Answer (score 5):

Expanding on @chepner's comments, here's how you could test for an unset (as opposed to set to a possibly empty value) variable:

```
if [ -z "${lastUpdated+set}" ]; then
```

The `${variable+word}` syntax gives an empty string if `$variable` is unset, and the string "word" if it's set:

```
$ fullvar=somestring
$ emptyvar=
$ echo "<${fullvar+set}>"
<set>
$ echo "<${emptyvar+set}>"
<set>
$ echo "<${unsetvar+set}>"
<>
```

Comment: @panepeter True, but my experience is that it's easier and safer to just double-quote variable references than it is to figure out when it's safe to leave them off. In this case, the fact that it *requires* a detailed explanation (including understanding what `[ -z ]` does and why) mans it's much easier to use double-quotes. To put it another way: if someone thinks `[ -z ${lastUpdated+set} ]` is a good way to test for a set variable, they're likely to infer that `[ -n ${lastUpdated+set} ]` is a good way to test for an unset variable, but it will completely fail.

Answer (score 4):

To sum it all up: There is no real *null* value in bash. Chepner's comment is on point:

> The bash documentation uses null as a synonym for the empty string.

Therefore, checking for null would mean checking for an **empty string**:

```
if [ "${lastUpdated}" = "" ]; then 
    # $lastUpdated is an empty string
fi
```

If what you really want to do is check for an **unset or empty** (i.e. "", i.e. '*null*') variable, use trojanfoe's approach:

```
if [ -z "$lastUpdated" ]; then
    # $lastUpdated could be "" or not set at all
fi
```

If you want to check weather the variable is unset, but are fine with empty strings, Gordon Davisson's answer is the way to go:

```
if [ -z ${lastUpdated+set} ]; then
    # $lastUpdated is not set
fi
```

([Parameter Expansion](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02) is what's going here)